# Excel VBA Loop find x and remove row - error

Tags: excel, vba, loops, find

I used record macro to create some code and then I put it in a loop. It works but there is an error in the find function which causes it to only work once. I tried to do something with the error but I am not having any luck having it loop. I've looked a couple of days here and there but I am at a loss. Hope you can help me. Much appreciated.

```
i = 1
On Error GoTo notfound
 Do While Sheet1.Cells(i, 1) <> "" 
   
 Columns("J:J").Select
    Selection.Find(What:="x", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
  LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
  MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
        
        Rows(ActiveCell.Row).EntireRow.Delete

notfound: msgbox "Finished"
GoTo notfound
Exit Sub
   
   i = i + 1
   
   Loop
```

Comment: Can you describe what you want the code to do?

Answer (score 0):

I've corrected, completed, formatted and commented your code. This should take you one step closer to what you want to do.

```
Private Sub Sample()

    Dim Crit        As Variant      ' the criterium to look for
    Dim Fnd         As Range        ' the cell to find
    Dim i           As Long
    
    ' never create an error handler if you don't know which error to exect
'    On Error GoTo notfound
    i = 1
    ' the cell can't be "" only its value can do thjat
    Do While Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""
        Crit = "x"
'        Columns("J:J").Select
        ' don't Select anything, address cells or ranges instead
        Set Fnd = Columns("J:J").Find(What:=Crit, _
                                      After:=ActiveCell, _
                                      LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                      LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                      SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                                      SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                      MatchCase:=False, _
                                      SearchFormat:=False)
        ' where is the 'Activecell'?
        '   a) it doesn't change while this loop is running
        '      but it might get deleted by this loop's action
        '   b) it must be in the range you are searching
        '      that's why your code will fail most of the time.
        
        ' don't Activate anything. Instead address the object you want to deal with.
        If Fnd Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "I didn't find """ & Crit & """"
        Else
            Sheet1.Rows(Fnd.Row).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

This code will look for "x" in column J for as long as there is a value in column A and delete the row where it is found. It's hard to imagine a relationship between the number of entries in column A and the number of "x" in column J but, hopefully, this isn't your problem. Instead, your obvious problem is the cell in which you want to start the search. It definitely isn't `ActiveCell` but it might be `Cells(1, "J")`. You can also omit this instruction and VBA will start the search after J1.

You want to `LookIn` formulas. If there are formulas in column J the `Formula` will be different from the `Value`. You may wish to search in `xlValues`.

Comment: Thank you Variatus for your attempted. I tried the code you sent and thoroughly went through the comments. Unfortunately, it is giving me a type mismatch error for the Find Function. I will keep messing with it to see if I can get it to work. As for the information there are 30 Columns and if there is an "X" in the J column the data is not needed in the entire row. I could really reference any column to have something but the first column always will. Just wanted to add that there will never be a formula in the J column. An "x" in it literally means cancelled.

Comment: Update: Variatus, I got it to work by removing everything from the find function but "Crit" I guess it didn't like some of the other criteria. I don't know what it was but oh well. Thanks again. Now I just need to figure out how to close the message box. I click close and it opens again. I figured it is going through the loop in some ways. It takes 16 times clicking ok to close. I'll keep working on it.

Comment: I fixed it not closing. I just added "Exit Do" after the message box. The code is now working as I want it to. Thanks again.

Comment: The `Find` function doesn't work because of the `After` property. *ActiveCell* is wrong. I suggested to remove that property. Just delete the line. The MsgBox will be shown every time the `Find` function returns no result. If your loop loops 16 times it may be shown 16 times. You are right to take appropriate action at that point of the code. However, the reason for not finding *Crit* might be because you look in `xlFormulas` instead of `xlValues`. If *Crit* is a different value on each loop exiting may not be the appropriate action to take.